# RTP MCU (media projector) design

Tags: rtp

I'm trying to build RTP media projector for only audio streams.
A user will create a session with the server and possibly broadcast audio stream.
The server will send to the user audio streams of all the other active users.

Can the server send media from a single port or does it need to be able to use a range of ports for sending? (I know it needs to listen to ports 1024 - 65535).
Does the server need to use ICE or can it just respond to the SDP request right away?

How does RTCP works in this scenario? Does the server sends quality of service feedback in the name of clients or acts as a client and sends feedback for himself?
What does the server do with quality of service feedback from the clients?

Does the server need to do something with the media packets like changing timestamps or just deliver them as is, assuming all clients are using the G.711 codec?

Thanks

Comment: Your design is not clear from your explanation. And you have asked too many questions. If you are done with the design then please share your design, If not then please let us know where you are with your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MCU can use a single port if it is the passive side in the peer-to-peer connection or a separate port for each session if it is the active side.

The MCU can act as a Translator and just forward RTCP packets from clients but this might result with high bandwidth usage. A more complicated MCU can parse RTCP packets and generate RTCP reports from this info.

The MCU need to decrypt and re-encrypt the RTP packets but as long as all the participants are using the same codec, there is no need for transcoding.

The info can be found in the RTP rfc
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt